# jquery not running with rails in external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

i am using rails and trying to call jquery code present in external js file whose path i have specified correctly in my html file.The jquery code is executing correctly when i include it directly  in html file.
my test.js

```
$(function(){

alert("yes");
});
```

and index.html.erb :

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/views/test.js"></script>

</head>
```

jquery executes when included inside html

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

alert("yes");
});
</script>
</head>
```

the test.js path is correct since other javascript functions are getting called from the same file but not jquery code

Comment: try include this file in your application.js .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you have head tag in index.html.erb file . It already included in layout/application.html.erb file . in this way you are including jquery file twice. If you include two versions of jquery in any html they always create issue.

In my suggestion you need to remove your head tag from index file completely . And what ever js file you want to include, include it in your application.js file. for current scenario you can do it like below.

```
//= require views/test
```

Comment: this was one of the issues causing the problem.thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

@user3946910

Try like this.

in your index.html

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/views/test.js"></script>

</head>
```

and in your test.js file add this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("yes");
});
```

Like this just import all plugins in the html itself, and create fresh .js page to write just your own script.

I hope it will help.